# Custom binding handler in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, aurelia

I want to create custom binding handlers in Aurelia based application(s), similar to custom binding handler in [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Please don't suggest about templates or custom elements.

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Without an example of what you want to achieve, we really can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Custom attributes. It's not the same, but maybe does what you want.

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-attributes/4